# Conditional alternative table row styles in HTML5

Tags: css, html, html-table

Is there any changes regarding this questions [Conditional alternative table row styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355875/conditional-alternative-table-row-styles) since HTML5 came in?

Here is a copy of original question:

Is it possible to style alternate table rows without defining classes on alternate  tags?

With the following table, can CSS define alternate row styles WITHOUT having to give the alternate rows the class "row1/row2"? row1 can be default, so row2 is the issue.

```
  <style>
  .altTable td { }
  .altTable .row2 td { background-color: #EEE; }
  </style>

  <table class="altTable">
   <thead><tr><td></td></tr></thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr class="row2"><td></td></tr>
    <tr><td></td></tr>
    <tr class="row2"><td></td></tr>
   </tbody>
  </table>
```

Answer (score 5):

CSS3 supports the "nth-child" property on the tr tag.  Something like the following should work:

```
tr:nth-child(odd)  { background-color: white; }
tr:nth-child(even) { background-color: green; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Jacob R's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1355875/conditional-alternative-table-row-styles/1357001#1357001) to your original posting still applies.

Comment: But author told: "Does not work in IE"..? Do you mean it is ok?

Comment: It still doesn't work in IE, sadly.  For IE, you will have to continue with the alternating classes or use JS to add the striping in.